# Map to Proj of ring of sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes, line-bundles

Let $X$ be an $A$-scheme ($A$ a ring) and $\mathscr{L}$ be a line bundle on $X$. Define the ring of sections of $\mathscr{L}$ to be $R(X,\mathscr{L})=\bigoplus _{n\geq 0} \Gamma(X,\mathscr{L^{\otimes n}})$, and let $Y=Proj(R(X,\mathscr{L}))$.

Apparently if the ring is finitely generated and $\mathscr{L}$ corresponds to an effective divisor then there is a rational map $X \dashrightarrow Y$, how is this map defined? What do we use the finite generation of the ring of the effectiveness for?

And if $\mathscr{L}$ is ample then $Y$ is the image of the map defined by $\mathscr{L}$, $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_A^n$, why is this?

Update: As one comment mentioned this is related to Hartshorne II.7.1, I am aware of this correspondence between n+1 generating global sections of a line bundle and maps to $\mathbb{P}^n_A$, which is what I referred to when I said "the map defined by $\mathscr{L}$, $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_A^n$". I don't know how to use the construction one usually does to get map to projective space using sections to show that the image of the map given by $\mathscr{L}$ lands in $Y$.

Comment: Hartshorne II.7.1 I think, and other stuff around that might help too.

Comment: Right now it seems like you haven't done much searching on your own before asking this question. Have you attempted to find these statements and their proofs in standard textbooks or on the internet? If so, it would improve your post to include this information, and if not, you should do it *before* asking here - see [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for why this is important on this website.

Comment: I added a small update, I'm not sure if it makes you feel better. I'm stuck because I can't find the construction of the map of interest explicitly anywhere and I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: A point $p \in X$ is mapped to the ideal determined by the subspaces of sections of each power of $\mathscr L$ which vanish at $p$.

Comment: You could try looking at §3.7 in [EGAII](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1961__8__5_0) for a description of the map $X \dashrightarrow Y$.